# Can a substance be extracted from solution by adding another substance with a higher solubility?

Tags: physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solutions

Suppose that I have a substance X dissolved in water. I then add a substance Y to the solution. Substance Y has a higher solubility in water than substance X, and more than enough of substance Y is added to saturate the water. Will substance X come out of solution? Why or why not?
For example, let's have X be sodium chloride and Y be sucrose.

Comment: Essentially, what you describe is a [solting out process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salting_out). Usually it's impossible to predict a priori whether it will or will not work, and how effective, so there is no uniform answer unless you provide a system to look into.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/79136/increasing-partition-coefficient-in-an-extraction